# Scrolling <marquee> and web form

Tags: javascript, html, marquee

I have installed a large **building automation system** with a **kiosk** at the front desk that displays energy savings and current energy consumption.

I was asked if I could add a `ticker` along the bottom that has announcements.

I don't know how to fully go about doing this and was looking for some direction.

And was thinking of using **html** and `<marquee>` to source text from a small database, then create a web based form on a separate page that would accept user input then overwrite the previous entry in the database to update the marquee.

I am looking for a direction to go in order to do this.

I am entry level when it comes to common industry languages because all of my programming experience revolves around proprietary languages developed for building automation systems.

Comment: Just this: `marquee` is [deprecated and might not work anymore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee). You should not use this element anymore.

Comment: @domsson Understood. It looks like CSS animation and keyframes is the way to go now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a database would be required. You could store the data in a JSON file and JSON works well with Js. Also, you won't have to learn SQL and a server side language like PHP if you use JSON with Js. 
For reference, I would recommend using w3schools, as they have all the details that you will need.

Hope that helps and any questions just comment below.

Comment: If I could avoid using a database that would be ideal, but most BAS systems utilize a database system with SQL being the one I am most familiar with.
I read a little bit quickly about JSON and it does appear that I can put the information into a JSON file. I just need to figure out how to write it, then read it.

It is frustrating to know what actions you wish to perform but don't have the language fluency to perform them.

Comment: I agree with what your saying and therefore I can help you since this is a very small project. Best JSON and JS reference site would be w3schools.com

Comment: I will look into the sites as reference and I will come up with some code to see if I can even get close. I am currently in a degree program for networking which consists of several programming courses. This semester is VB as intro to object based programming. Building automation has taken a sharp turn to ip networks and web based delivery so I am trying to keep up.

Comment: I am free on holidays at the moment, so I can help you with this small project. Feel free to contact me: championno99@hotmail.com